# Resampling data to target grid

Tags: python, list, interpolation, resampling

Is there an efficient way to solve the following problem?

Imagine we have these 2 lists. They represent non-uniformly sampled data:

```
MeasTimes = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 18, 20, 22]
MeasValues = [-1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

How does one interpolate the data from this measurement to a target grid? 
Example:

```
TargetTimes = [0, 5, 10, 15, 18, 20] # given
```

Comment: How did you determine the "wanted" result? By strict lookup the values for 18 & 20 don't make sense, and what is the criteria for values between two samples, are they interpolated or use high ro low?

Comment: yp jessag, I was just extrapolating. Maybe I should remove the MeasValuesAtTargetTimes.

Comment: @dpgomez you are interpolating right? you get e.g. the value for MeasValuesAtTargetTimes[2] from (MeasValues[2]+MeasValues[3])/2. Is that what you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
meas_times = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 18, 20, 22]
meas_values = [-1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

def get_value(target_value):
    if target_value in meas_times:
        return meas_values[meas_times.index(target_value)]
    else:
        upper_index, upper_time = next((i, e) for i, e in enumerate(meas_times) if e > target_value)
        lower_value, upper_value = meas_values[upper_index - 1], meas_values[upper_index]
        abs_dt = float(abs(lower_value) + abs(upper_value)) / (upper_time - meas_times[upper_index - 1])

        if upper_value > lower_value:
            return lower_value + abs_dt * (target_value - meas_times[upper_index - 1])
        else:
            return lower_value - abs_dt * (target_value - meas_times[upper_index - 1])

target_times = [0, 5, 10, 15, 18, 20]
print map(get_value, target_times)
# [-1, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: True interpolation would account for the time width not just 1/2 - i.e. 8-11 for 10 or 14-18 for 15.

Comment: Thx funkySayu. That is what I wanted.
And yes, I noticed my wanted result was actually incorrect, reflecting the fact that I wasn't being able to solve the problem. Therefore I removed it from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: But yes, optimally one should correct for the time width. Numpy.interp would consider "MeasValuesAtTargetTimes = [-1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]" to be correct.

Comment: @dpgomez you can update your question to clarify that you are interpolating. +1 for this answer.

Comment: I don't have the same result : [-1, 0.5, -0.16666666666666666, 0.0, 0, 1]

Comment: funny, I tried new_values = np.interp(target_grid,old_grid,old_values). I guess that should be correct...

Comment: Okay... I did it wrong, because I forgot there was some negatives values. The real script is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think in times you have give wrong data ( 5 and 10)

the Code is

```
MeasValuesAtTargetTimes=[MeasValues[MeasTimes.index(i)] for i in TargetTimes]
```